# Hide component on condition which contains the component which should be displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, show-hide

I have a component which I render on a button click. How can I say something like "hide everything which gets not rendered on the button click".

If the following button gets clicked:

```jsx
<button class="button" onClick={() => setShowCheckout(true)}>order now</button>
```

This part of my code gets rendered:

```jsx
{showCheckout && (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <Route exact path="/">
            <Cart cart={cart} onUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty} onRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart} onEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart} />
        </Route>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/cart">
            <Cart cart={cart} onUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty} onRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart} onEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/checkout" exact>
            <Checkout cart={cart} order={order} onCaptureCheckout={handleCaptureCheckout} error={errorMessage} />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </div>) 
}
```

How can I create now something which hides all the code which is not inside this code block?

Here is all of my code:

```jsx
return (
    <Router>
        <div class="container_landing_page" id="test">
            <div class="container_landing_page_left">
            <div class="container_headline_landing_page">
              <div class="box_landing_page">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div class="container_headline_landing_page_CRISPR"><a>CRISPR</a> <br /> <a>EDUCATION KIT</a></div>
                <div></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container_bullet_points_landing_page">
              <div class="container_bullet_points_landing_page_2">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="underlineH">Nuts and bolts CRISPR - Cas9</a></li>
                  <li><a class="underlineH">Scientific identity and promotion for STEM interest</a></li>
                  <li><a class="underlineH">Create your own bio systems</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container_order_button_landing_page">
              <div class="container_order_button_landing_page_2">
                <button class="button" onClick={() => setShowCheckout(true)}>
                  order now
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><div class="container_landing_page_right">
              <div class="container_image_landing_page">
                <img src={'/assets/dna.png'} alt="Logo" class="landing_page_image" />
              </div>
            </div>
          {showCheckout && (
            <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
              <Route exact path="/">
                  <Cart cart={cart} onUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty} onRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart} onEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart} />
              </Route>
              <CssBaseline />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/cart">
                  <Cart cart={cart} onUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty} onRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart} onEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/checkout" exact>
                  <Checkout cart={cart} order={order} onCaptureCheckout={handleCaptureCheckout} error={errorMessage} />
                </Route>
              </Switch>
            </div>) 
          }
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question is how to show only the part wrapped by the condition : `showCheckout` and hide all the other content, so you may wrap it by the opposite condition

```
return (
  <Router>
      <div class="container_landing_page" id="test">
          {!showCheckout && (
          <>
          <div class="container_landing_page_left">
          <div class="container_headline_landing_page">
            <div class="box_landing_page">
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div class="container_headline_landing_page_CRISPR"><a>CRISPR</a> <br /> <a>EDUCATION KIT</a></div>
              <div></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container_bullet_points_landing_page">
            <div class="container_bullet_points_landing_page_2">
              <ul>
                <li><a class="underlineH">Nuts and bolts CRISPR - Cas9</a></li>
                <li><a class="underlineH">Scientific identity and promotion for STEM interest</a></li>
                <li><a class="underlineH">Create your own bio systems</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container_order_button_landing_page">
            <div class="container_order_button_landing_page_2">
              <button class="button" onClick={() => setShowCheckout(true)}>
                order now
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><div class="container_landing_page_right">
            <div class="container_image_landing_page">
              <img src={'/assets/dna.png'} alt="Logo" class="landing_page_image" />
            </div>
          </div>
          </>
          )}
        {showCheckout && (
          <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            <Route exact path="/">
                <Cart cart={cart} onUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty} onRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart} onEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart} />
            </Route>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/cart">
                <Cart cart={cart} onUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty} onRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart} onEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart} />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/checkout" exact>
                <Checkout cart={cart} order={order} onCaptureCheckout={handleCaptureCheckout} error={errorMessage} />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>) 
        }
      </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Another suggestion is to split the component - id showCheckout is true - display the part you want, otherwise- display the second part

Answer (score 0):

I just created a additional condition which hides the component:

```jsx
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

return (
    <Router>
        {visible && <div class="container_landing_page" id="test">
          <div class="container_landing_page_left">
            <div class="container_headline_landing_page">
              <div class="box_landing_page">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div class="container_headline_landing_page_CRISPR"><a>CRISPR</a> <br /> <a>EDUCATION KIT</a></div>
                <div></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container_bullet_points_landing_page">
              <div class="container_bullet_points_landing_page_2">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="underlineH">Nuts and bolts CRISPR - Cas9</a></li>
                  <li><a class="underlineH">Scientific identity and promotion for STEM interest</a></li>
                  <li><a class="underlineH">Create your own bio systems</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container_order_button_landing_page">
              <div class="container_order_button_landing_page_2">
                <button class="button"  onClick={() => {setShowCheckout(true); setVisible(false)}}>
                  order now
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container_landing_page_right">
            <div class="container_image_landing_page">
              <img src={'/assets/dna.png'} alt="Logo" class="landing_page_image" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>}
          {showCheckout && (
            <div style={{ display: 'flex' }} class="ignore-css">
              <Route exact path="/">
                  <Cart cart={cart} onUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty} onRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart} onEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart} />
              </Route>
              <CssBaseline />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/cart">
                  <Cart cart={cart} onUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty} onRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart} onEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/checkout" exact>
                  <Checkout cart={cart} order={order} onCaptureCheckout={handleCaptureCheckout} error={errorMessage} />
                </Route>
              </Switch>
            </div>) 
          }
    </Router>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the rendering part of your code seems rather complicated, you should make it simpler. E.g :

```
 <Router>
    <div class="container_landing_page" id="test">
    {renderLandingPage()}
    {renderXXX()}
    ...
  </div>
  </Router>
```

With this way you can manage visibility easily
E.g :

```
  renderXXX(){
     if(showCheckout)
        return "current render..."

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you trying to hide the first part of your code **after the first render**, i mean you render firstly all of your code and after click the button you want to render two-part reversely. If you want to do that, you should define another state like showCheckout, and after the first click that variable should turn false and you should let the only showCheckout determine elements to render. For example

```
function onChangeVisible() {
    if (firstPartVisible) {
        setFirstPartVisible(false);

    }
    setShowCheckout(!showCheckout)
}


return (
 // <button class="button" onClick={() => onChangeVisible()}>order now</button>
  <Router>
      <div class="container_landing_page" id="test">
          {firstPartVisible || !showCheckout && (
          <>
          <div class="container_landing_page_left">
          <div class="container_headline_landing_page">
            <div class="box_landing_page">
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div class="container_headline_landing_page_CRISPR"><a>CRISPR</a> <br /> <a>EDUCATION KIT</a></div>
              <div></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container_bullet_points_landing_page">
            <div class="container_bullet_points_landing_page_2">
              <ul>
                <li><a class="underlineH">Nuts and bolts CRISPR - Cas9</a></li>
                <li><a class="underlineH">Scientific identity and promotion for STEM interest</a></li>
                <li><a class="underlineH">Create your own bio systems</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container_order_button_landing_page">
            <div class="container_order_button_landing_page_2">
              <button class="button" onClick={() => setShowCheckout(true)}>
                order now
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><div class="container_landing_page_right">
            <div class="container_image_landing_page">
              <img src={'/assets/dna.png'} alt="Logo" class="landing_page_image" />
            </div>
          </div>
          </>
          )}
        {showCheckout && (
          <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            <Route exact path="/">
                <Cart cart={cart} onUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty} onRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart} onEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart} />
            </Route>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/cart">
                <Cart cart={cart} onUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty} onRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart} onEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart} />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/checkout" exact>
                <Checkout cart={cart} order={order} onCaptureCheckout={handleCaptureCheckout} error={errorMessage} />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>) 
        }
      </div>
  </Router>
);
```